# How to start Drb service concurrently with other methods in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, multithreading, drb

I want to run the `startdrb` method concurrently with the `printstuff` method on a Windows system. I messed around with `Thread.new` but the service starts and terminates after the thread completes.

How would this be written?

```
require 'drb'
require 'drb/ssl'

class TestDRB
  def dostuff
    ...
  end

  def startdrb
    begin
      config = {SSLCertName: [["CN","DRuby"]]}
      DRb.start_service("drbssl://127.0.0.1:9911", BHRBeacon.new, config)
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.full_message
    end

  def printstuff  
    begin
      puts "this will run while Drb service is also running"
    end

TestDRB.new.startdrb
TestDRB.new.printstuff
```

Comment: Check out the Threads and Processes chapter of [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

Comment: I believe the Process class is only for linux. as for Threads, I have tried Thread.new {TestDRB.new.startdrb} and it does not continue execution until there is an interrupt. So it is not concurrent